# Returning a Script Refernce using WebMethod does not get executed

Tags: jquery, ajax

If i try yo use WebMethod to return an HTML code that contains a script reference like

```
   <script src="js/components/MyJS.js" id="testScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All the content returned using HTML i bind it to a span.

Problem:

This script does not get executed in Safari but all other.

I try to hard code the entire html then it get executed but not if i get the complete html as a string using AJAX and then bind it to some html tag.

Code for getting html:

```
var control = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: opts.url,
        data: "{control_name : '" + opts.control_name + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        cache: false,
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error occured textStatus=" + textStatus + " errorThrown=" + errorThrown);
        },


        success: function (msg) {

            control.html(msg.d);

        }
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is because of Jquery library.

If i try to use minified version it does not work but full version work. It seems too be strange.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `getScript` instead: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Something like:

```
    success: function (msg) {

        $.getScript(msg.d);

    }
```

Where you're WebMethod return only the path to the script file.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify a charset in the html page that is doing the request.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```